# Not able to navigate user in.Undefined is not an object(evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate)

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am using `react-navigation` for routing in my react app. Whenever I click on sign up button and it shows

> Undefined is not an object(evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate)

**Frontend Logic**

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
  }
}
register(){
  API.userRegister(this.state)
  .then((user) => {
    //if(user===this.state)
    if(user.username === this.state.username && user.password === this.state.password){
      // ToastAndroid.show(user.message, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Inside')
    }
    else{
      ToastAndroid.show(user.message, ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }
  })
}
```

**API POsT method**

```
     static post(url, headers, body, resolve, reject){
    fetch(`${this.baseUrl}${url}`,{
        headers: headers,
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
        .then((resp) => {
            resolve(resp.json());
        })
        .catch(err => reject(err))
}
```

**API file code**

```
 static userRegister(data){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.post(`/register`, {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }, data, resolve, reject)
    });
}
```

**Backend Logic**

```
class UserRegister(Resource):

def post(self):
  data = _user_parser.parse_args()

  if UserModel.find_by_username(data['username']):
    return {"message": "A user with that name is already existed"},400

  user = UserModel(**data)
  user.save_to_db()

  return {"username": data["username"], "password": data["password"], "message": "User created successfully"}, 201
```

Comment: which routing library are you using?

Comment: @RaghavGarg Sir, its react-navigation

Comment: Please don't call me sir. It's not a backend issue, so I guess you can remove the backend code, but show more of your frontend logic, like, how are you binding component with it while exporting the it?

Comment: @RaghavGarg I edited the code

Comment: Did you create stackNavigation at your App ?

Comment: yes @DarknessZX on login function it works.but not on registering